# White text color on Pixel 6 android

Tags: android, android-edittext, google-pixel, android-text-color

I have an app available on play store and users have been reporting that they can enter any text due to the fact that the text color is white, which very weird.
I have used Firebase Test Lab to try reproduce the issue. I could indeed reproduce it.
On Pixel 5, everything is fine and the input text on `EditText` is visible. Text is black and background is white.
On Pixel 6 on the other hand, there is nothing to see.
I have not set any text color on the edit text, so everything is out of the box.
Unfortunately there is not yet an Emulator for Pixel 6 in android studio. Therefore I can't really debug to see what's going on.

What is so new on Pixel 6 that sets white as the text color?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve the problem.Changing the parent of my style from `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` did the trick.

Comment: This is dark theme rather than particular device issue. Most likely you've set the background explicitly to white while allowing foreground to be theme-dependent. You must either set  both or none at all. Locking entire app out of dark mode is a lousy hack that your users will despise.